# Convex polyhedra, combinatorial types and Symmetry

Tags: graph-theory, polyhedra, symmetry

Steinitz theorem says that combinatorial types of convex polyhedra is identified with 3-connected planar graph, called by a **polyhedral graph**.

A symmetry of polyhedral graph means that a vertex permutation( where the corresponding edges/faces permutations are also induced from vertices) preserving the combinatorial type. We can easily check that this is realized as a planar isotopy and reflection on 2-sphere. I want to say this is **combinatorial symmetry** and consider the group of combinatorial symmetries for  a polyhedral graph.

Now, my question is the following.

Let us consider  a polyhedral graph and the  combinatorial symmetry group. 
Is there  a Euclidean convex polyhedron of the polyhedral graph whose combinatorial symmetry group can be  realized as  Euclidean isometries?

For example, $K_4$ has the tetrahedral symmetry group. If one consider regular tetrahedra in Euclidean space, the all tetrahedral symmetries can be realized as Euclidean isometries.

Is this true for all polyhedral graph? 
.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is true for all polyhedral graphs. See the following reference:

[P. Mani, *Automorphismen von polyedrischen Graphen*, Mathematische Annalen Volume 192, Issue 4, pp 279-303, August 1971](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02075357)

[image: Satz von Mani]

My translation:

**Theorem.** *For every graph $\mathfrak{Q}$* there is a three dimensional convex polyhedron $P$ with the properties:

(a) $\mathfrak{Q}$ is isomorphic to vertex-edge skeleton $\mathfrak{P}^1$ of $P$

(b) Every automorphism of $\mathfrak{P}^1$ is induced by a symmetry of the polyhedron $P$.

See this [mathscinet link](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=296808) for an english summary of the result.